# Cache Optimizations for adding 2 long vector

Tags: caching, vector, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Given 2 long vectors 2000 element each are to be added on machine with 32 byte cache line (single level cache) and a CPU. We have to add these 2 vectors such that sum goes in a new vector.
e.g. `c[0]=a[0]+b[0], c[1]=a[1]+b[1], c[2]=a[2]+b[2]......... c[1999]=a[1999]+b[1999]`

I know when `c[0]=a[0]+b[0]` is done we will have `a[0]to a[31], b[0]to b[31], c[0]to c[31]` in cache . So we will get a cache miss at every 32nd element. Somebody asked me this:

Can you optimize it more for getting better performance (over what I stated above. Cache miss only at 32 element because of locality)?

I am sure there is something more to this that I don't know.

Comment: The question is very vague, but if the CPU has some kind of prefetch mechanism then that may be one way to avoid the cache misses.

Comment: I mean is there any way , like doing summations in some order that can improve more performance. Accessing them serially like a[0] , a[1] ... will help me get cache hits owing to locality. Can this paradigm get benefited  from some cache oblivious programming optimization to get more performance.

Comment: Not really - you've got to pay for cache misses one way or another. The only other cache-related optimisation for this kind of situation is to make it destructive (in place), i.e. `a[i] += b[i]` but you seem to have explicitly ruled this out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a modern superscalar CPU with out-of-order execution, you can use a technique called [software pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining) to help mitigate the cost of cache misses. E.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

becomes:

```
ai = a[0];
bi = b[0];
ci = ai + bi;
ai = a[1];
bi = b[1];
for (i = 0; i < N - 2; ++i)
{
    c[i] = ci;           // note that within this loop the order of operations has
    ci = ai + bi;        // been reversed - instead of load-add-store we now have
    ai = a[i + 2];       // store-add-load - this reduces serial dependencies
    bi = b[i + 2];
}
c[i] = ci;
ci = ai + bi;
c[i + 1] = ci;
```

Typically a total cache miss costs 100s of cycles (DRAM latency), so in this simple case the overlapping of loads/stores and arithmetic will make only a very small difference, but for complex examples software pipelining can sometimes be useful.

Having said that, most modern CPUs now have automatic (hardware) prefetch, so software pipelining has become less useful than it used to be. Also many of these explicit optimisations are now handled automatically by good compilers.

Comment: For this microbenchmark, there would also be some advantage in avoiding read-for-ownership for 'c'. The Power ISA provides Data Cache Block Zero (and DCB Allocate) instructions that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: To expand the comment by @PaulA.Clayton - in x86 you could use write-combining with streaming stores, which would attempt to merge all the writes to the same cacheline and avoid having to read the data. see - http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/